# How to display content using separate aliases, menu/breadcrumb selections, taxonomy links based on context using Drupal

Tags: drupal, breadcrumbs, aliases

I'm building a site using Drupal that has content items (e.g. news articles) that can be linked to (aka tagged with) one or more 'projects'.

---

E.g. News Articles have this structure, and appear like this:

{Article Title}

{Article Image}

{Article Date}

{Article Body}

Projects: {Project 1}, {Project 2}, etc

---

I want to be able to access the news article in different contexts, e.g.

a) Home > News > {Article Title} - /news/{article-title}

b) Home > Projects > {Project Title} > News > {Article Title} - /projects/{project-title}/news/{article-title}

I've set up a content type so that news articles can be tagged with / linked to one or more projects.

---

Questions:

1) Aliases - How do I go about accessing a node via different URL aliases (e.g. news vs project news)?

2) Breadcrumbs - How do I go about maintaining the breadcrumb based on where the visitor accessed the news article on the site?

3) Menus - How do I go about maintaining the correct menu selection based on where the visitor accessed the news article on the site?

4) Taxonomy/Tag links - How do I go about changing the "project" tag link to link to the project page vs the generic taxonomy page?

Comment: I asked a few people on the #drupal-support IRC channel. First of all they said that having duplicate content is a 'terrible' idea.

Comment: So I basically see two options: 1) have all the news items live under Home > News and take the user to another section of the site (easy) or 2) figure out how to do all of the above and add meta tags to avoid negatively impacting search engine rankings (assuming that that is actually true)